# Java Recursion.. need help understanding the solution of the recursive case

Tags: recursion, data-structures

Write a method writeChars that accepts an integer parameter n and that prints out n characters as follows. The middle character of the output should always be an asterisk ("*"). If you are asked to write out an even number of characters, then there will be two asterisks in the middle ("**"). Before the asterisk(s) you should write out less-than characters ("<"). After the asterisk(s) you should write out greater-than characters (">").

I've managed to solve the problem but dont quite understand one statement:

```
public void writeChars(int n) {
    if ( n < 1 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    
    if( n == 1 ){
        System.out.print("*");
        return;
    }
    
    if ( n == 2 ) {
        System.out.print("**");
        return;
    }
    
    System.out.print("<");
    writeChars(n-2);
    System.out.print(">");
}
```

why is the recursive case:

```
writeChars(n-2);
```

n-2? instead of n-1?

Comment: Have you tried `n-1` to see what it does?

Comment: Yes, it was my first attempt and it doubled my characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every recursion call the code is printing exactly two outputs. Hence for every iteration the number should be decreased by two. 
If you write `n-1` then the number of characters its printing would become double. Hence we have to write, `n-2`
One print statement before the recursion statement and one after.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yeah that was my initial thought just wanted to confirm! THANK YOU :)